# Where produce is sold all year round in retail stands, booths and tables not necessarily by farmers

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

What is that kind of market called where fresh produce is sold **all year round** in retail stands, booths and tables but **not necessarily by farmers themselves.**

In **everyday English**, do you still call them **farmers markets**-if you do so- even though produce is sold by regular vendors?

Some sample photos and pictures are shown below

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'd just call it a market - non-specific. Doesn't even have to sell only food, could sell kitchenware too, so long as it's a collection of retail traders in kind of 'non-permanent' stalls it would qualify. Farmer's Market implies all the vendors grow their own, even if it's not true. [Over-used term in Br Eng, I think, playing on the connotation of it all being 'good, healthy stuff']

Comment: Some cities in the US have open-air street markets but they're unusual enough to be tourist attractions (in addition to serving the local communities). Small (authentic) farmers markets, quickie convenience stores, and large supermarkets are far more common here than open-air markets where the vendors are not the produce growers.

Comment: +1 @Tetsujin,TRomano. Do you both think that [Greenmarket](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/green+market) is used by common people without stretch of the language or being formal?

Comment: tbh, I've never heard the term greenmarket til now. UK Eng.

Answer (score 3):

It's just *[market, street market](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/market_1)* or anything that applies to it.

The example follows: *We buy our fruit and vegetables at the market*

When you tell me 'market', I understand it in a general way. You may need to emphasize vegetable market, fruit market or whatever market you are referring to. In other words, **if you want to be precise in** referring to 'farmers' market' you **will actually** have to call it 'farmers' market'.

Comment: +1 This one "**Thursday is market day**" is interesting too from your link.

Comment: However, if you told me that you buy your vegetables at the market I would assume you meant a supermarket or grocery store.  I would call the things in the pictures, "*produce stands*" which might be at a farmer's market.

Comment: @Jim It depends where do you live! In India, availability of vegetables in the supermarket happened a few years back! :) Even today, supermarkets and grocery stores are **not** the preferred places for getting vegetables for 70% of the population in India!